# Scala generics not correctly converted to Java in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, generics, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 with Java 1.8 and Scala 2.11.7

One scala class defines a method

```
def getLogger(c:Class[_]) =  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(c)
```

In the java class, I use this method via

```
getLogger(MyClass.class)
```

This has worked for a long time (and still works with colleges). Now IntelliJ claims, the `getLogger` method requires `java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>` instead of the correct `java.lang.Class<?>`.

I can still run the code (directly in IntelliJ or via mvn) but the inspection still shows the error.

Which settings could I change to correct this?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behaviour. Can you attach a screenshot?

Ticket on a [bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL) is a better way to handle such problems.

Comment: So far I assumed, this is a problem of my configuration and not a bug. Not sure, what I should screenshot, but here are the two classes in question. http://imgur.com/bpeD4Xt

Comment: You may try to do `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` . If you use a build tool like Maven or SBT, you may also try to delete `.idea` directory and reimport your project.

Comment: It seems that it's a regression introduced in scala-plugin 3.0.3:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a regression introduced in scala-plugin 3.0.3. Fix is available in 3.0.4.